# Database file export is empty

Tags: android, android-room

I have use app added some datas to the database. But when I try to use Device File Explorer to export the database file. I found it was empty but the app can read them. I've Synchronized the file but still didn't work.

Comment: Without a [mcve] it is difficult to help you. Bear in mind that Room uses write-ahead logging (WAL) in SQLite by default. So, either close your database before making the copy, or be sure to copy all the files, including those with weird suffixes like `-wal`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will likely be 3 files the database, one suffixed with **-wal**, the other suffixed with **-shm**. Copy all three files (or at least the database and the -wal file).

The **-wal** file, if it is not empty will contain changes awaiting to be applied to the database. The **-shm** file is a wal file for the -wal file and is less important.

WAL stands for write ahead logging you can find out more about it at https://sqlite.org/wal.html